# View status of service running on remote machine

Tags: vb.net, servicecontroller

The conditions are
- I don't have administrator privilege
- I want to see the status of a service in remote machine (server)

I use the following code (vb.net with framework 2.0) to see the status

```
Dim sqlSvc As ServiceController
Svc = New ServiceController(My.Settings.serviceName, My.Settings.machineName)
If sqlSvc.Status.ToString.Equals("Running") Then
    displayStatus("success", sqlSvc.Status.ToString)
Else
    displayStatus("error", sqlSvc.Status.ToString)
End If
```

When running the code, `InvalidOperationException` is raised and found out that I need admin right in the server.

Can I lookup the status of the service without having admin right in remote machine ?

Comment: I don't see a way that InvalidOperationException could be raised by this code.  You'd better post the StackTrace of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be admin on remote machine, but you do need at least SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS permission on the particular service you want to monitor. The local Administrators group has this, as does Power Users. Or you can create a group and grant it the permission with [subinacl.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E8BA3E56-D8FE-4A91-93CF-ED6985E3927B&displaylang=en) or [Security Templates](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_scetopnode.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

You can get two types of `System.InvalidOperationException` from this call, either `Service {X} was not found on computer '{Y}'` or `Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '{Y}'. This operation might require other privileges`. The first comes from an invalid service name and the second comes when either you don't have permission ***or more likely*** the machine name can't be found.

Also, don't use ToString() unless you have to. You've got an enum, use it:

```
If sqlSvc.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
```